# Run docker - Error parsing reference

Tags: docker, windows-7-x64

I am new with docker and have a problem with running a built image. I am using Docker on Windows 7 64bit.

```
$ docker run --rm -it --net=host -e DISPLAY -v -no-cache /c/nd-player:/home/developer/app marc/qt-zeromq:3.2.5 sh /c/nd-player/entrypoint.sh

C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe: Error parsing reference: "/c/nd-player:/home/developer/app" is not a valid repository/tag. See 'C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\docker.exe run --help'.
```

[image: desc]

Comment: Have you tried to run a more simple command? Like `docker run hello-world`?

Comment: Yeah, hello world runs fine.

Answer (score 0):

Move the `-no-cache` to another place. The folder mapping has to come directly after `-v`. Did you miss the container tag? I cannot see it.

Comment: If I move the `-no-cache` I get flag provided or not defined. Without `-no-cache` I have `/bin/sh: cannot execute binary file`. By missed tag you mean `-t`?

Comment: I mean the container tag. The `cannot execute` comes from the bash script `/c/nd-player/entrypoint.sh`. What is that? Can it run on Windows machines?

Comment: Hard to say for me:
`#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p .build
cd .build
qmake /home/developer/app/player.pro -r -spec linux-g++-64
make`

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The script runs on the container.

Comment: Is the container running although you got the error (`docker ps`)? Do you user Virtual Machine? I would suggest to move the data which is in `/c/nd-player` to your user directory. This will be auto mounted by Virtual Machine.

Comment: I kind of move on, now I am stucked with that only some folders are mounted.... Updated image in main post.